# Are "power" and "clout" perfect synonyms?

Tags: synonyms

Is there a slight difference between *power* and *clout* in the context of a political influence?

For instance:

> Asking China to help the euro world would give a non-eurozone nation the *power* to decide the fate of the currency

Is *clout* a *perfect synonym* of *power* in that context? Is the meaning the same? Is the level of language the same?

Comment: It's certainly not a "perfect" synonym, because *clout* is rather informal used in this way, and is somewhat negatively loaded. These connotations are avoided by the alternative **ability**, which I suggest *is* a perfect synonym in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 's comment is perfectly eligible for being a full answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merriam Webster defines clout as "pull, influence". This distinguishes it by degree from "power"...if you have clout, you may be able to influence the person with the power. But if you have power, you don't need clout.

Comment: Conversely, it may be said if you have clout, you don't need power. Just sayin'....

Comment: Well, I almost continued that clout could actually be better, because you don't have responsibility and accountability. There was a classic series called Yes, Minister which was basically about showing who was REALLY in power in the British government - the permanent civil service, and not the temporarily elected representatives...

Comment: -1 - this is a contrived distinction.

Comment: Here's an interesting example: ACCESS TO POWER: BUILDING POLITICAL CLOUT FOR THE ARTS: http://www.nasaa-arts.org/Advocacy/Advocacy-Tools/advocate_access.pdf.

Comment: *Power, clout, influence, authority, control,* etc. are all capable of being used to mean exactly the same thing. Of that (non-exhaustive) list, I'd say that *influence* is the best one for the "power by association" meaning you ascribe to *clout*. Some, of course, would say that even politicians don't have the real power - they've just got influence over the ultra-rich people who actually have it.